# Return same format as requests for JSON errors in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I currently have a Phoenix application that has both JSON and HTML endpoints.

I would like to return the errors that are the most appropriate for the given request, but it always defaults to the `render("XXX.html, _)` function even when the request's format is `application/json`.

Is there a way to return JSON for requests of type `application/json` and HTML for everything else?

Comment: That should get you started -> https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#get_format/1

Comment: yeah, but the error render function doesn't give you the connection i thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna check the `render_errors` option (see [docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.6.2/docs/custom-errors)) in your `config.exs` file and add the `json` format as well as `html`.

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  # ...
  render_errors: [view: MyApp.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json)]
```

Also, be sure to be sending the appropriate `Accept` header.

Comment: The Accept header wasn't set. Thanks.